# JS: related objects

Tags: javascript, oop

Scenario:
 - fill object1
 - copying the content of object1 to object2
 - delete element from object1

Result now:
 - both object1 and object2 have 1 element deleted...?!

Wished result:
 - object1 should have 1 element less than object2

The code:

```
var object1 = new Object();
object1['key_one']   = 'value_1';
object1['key_two']   = 'value_2';
object1['key_three'] = 'value_3';
object1['key_four']  = 'value_4';
var object2 = new Object();
object2 = object1;
delete object1['key_three'];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i do not see any relation with multidimensional arrays..

Comment: Your code does not match your explanation.  I suspect that you are doing a shallow copy, but your code does no copy at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not do any copying.  `object2` is simply a new, empty object.  Try this:

```
var object1 = {
  key_one: "value_1",
  key_two: "value_2",
  key_three: "value_3",
  key_four: "value_4"
};
var object2 = {};
for (var prop in object1) {
  object2[prop] = object1[prop];
}
delete object1["key_three"];
```

Now `object2` is a copy of `object1`, but deleting properties from `object1` will not affect `object2`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: bcherry, you saved my day, it works! thanks a thousand times! stackoverflow rules!

Comment: @Ozcar: Mark this answer correct, then. Give the man some rep!

Comment: @Ozcar: don't forget to use `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: yeah, if you have a code base that modifies `Object.prototype`, then `hasOwnProperty` is important.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me like object2 ever received any of the properties of object1. You're on the right track, but you need to copy them.

```
var object1 = new Object();
object1['key_one']   = 'value_1';
object1['key_two']   = 'value_2';
object1['key_three'] = 'value_3';
object1['key_four']  = 'value_4';

var object2 = new Object();
for(var i in object1){
    object2[i] =  object1[i];
}
delete object1['key_three'];
```